# Use SSH to pipe tcpdump into wireshark with "command" in authorized_keys

Tags: linux, ssh, wireshark, tracing

we want to enable real-time network tracing for Application Testing.

We want to grant as little permissions/rights on the remote host that will run tcpdump.

So i tried to setup an authorized key that is used for login.

```
command="sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0 -s 65535 -w -" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC....
```

When i connect from the client machine and use

```
ssh -i private.key user@10.10.254.200 | wireshark -S -k -i -
```

Wireshark complains and says "unrecognzied pcap format"

When we instead run

```
 ssh -i private.key user@10.10.254.200 "tcpdump -i eth0 -w -" | wireshark -S -k -i -
```

and remove the command="..." from authorized keys it works!

What is the difference of these two variants? if i remove the "| wireshark..." in both cases i see binary data comming towards me in the terminal...

In case there is a difference that will make this impossible in any case, do you guys know a way where the command can somehow be pre-defined on server side?

As i tried to explain in the beginning, the client machines that run wireshark shall be as restricted as possible.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case it is normal ssh session with pseudo-terminal.

If you want just the data (without terminal control characters and stuff like that), you should try `ssh` with `-T` switch.

The other solution how to achieve the same behaviour is to put `no-pty` next to the command in `authorized_keys` file (thanks @mykel):

```
command="sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0 -s 65535 -w -",no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC....
```

Comment: @aslmx you are welcome. Marking as an answer would help

Comment: You could also achieve this by adding the `no-pty` option into the `authorized_keys` file.